# Use comma separated value of a single cell as input for array formula

Tags: excel, vba

I want to built an array formula that accepts separated values of a single cell as input:

Cell A1: 1;3;4

Cell A2: ={Sum(If(A3:F3)=A1,A4:F4))}

How can I tell excel to intepret the string in A1 as array?
I tried to set up a custom vba function, but I was not able to return the vba array correctly to the excel formula.

Can anyone help?

[image: Screenshot]

What I tried with VBA:

```
Function Matrix(vector)
Dim arr As Variant

arr = Array(Split(vector, ";"))
Matrix = arr


End Function
```

In the above formula I replace A1 by Matrix(A1).
But the values of the vectors are returned as strings instead of integers (sorry, actually using a german Excel):

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks
Peter

Comment: See my Edit. Thanks!

Comment: `Split` returns an array, so what is the point of `Array` in `Array(Split(vector, ";"))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some clever so-and-so will provide you with a formula I expect, but here is a VBA solution. You need to pass two arguments (at least) I think - the array and look-up range.

```
Function Matrix(vector, r As Range) As Variant

Dim arr As Variant, i As Long, v As Variant

arr = Split(vector, ";")

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    v = Application.Match(Val(arr(i)), r.Rows(1), 0)
    If IsNumeric(v) Then Matrix = Matrix + r(2, v)
Next i

End Function
```

The formula in C1 is

```
=matrix(A1,A3:D4)
```

Note that `Split` returns an array.

[image]

Comment: Yes. Completely agree that the whole thing (Split and Match) should be a UDF.

Comment: My pleasure. You might also want to build in some error checking in case cells don't contain numbers. On reflection you could utilise HLOOKUP here.